# Prioritize city matches against province matches in Nominatim

Tags: javascript, geocoding, nominatim, maplibre-gl

I installed Nominatim in combination with the Maplibre geocoder, but I am having troubles getting the results in the correct order of relevance or getting the correct one at all. In Italy many provinces have the same name as the capital of the province, for example Cagliari is both the name of the Province and the name of a city. When I search for

```
Via Roma, Cagliari
```

I an expecting to see the result for the street "Via Roma" located in the city of Cagliari, but I get results for "Via Roma" in other cities located in the province of Cagliari instead. This happens frequently with street names that are fairly common across cities in the same area. How can I make Nominatim to give precedence to the street located in the city with the same name or to not take the province into account at all when elaborating the query?

This is how I am calling the geocoder api

```
var geocoder_api = {
  forwardGeocode: async (config) => {
    const features = [];
    try {
      geocoder_bbox = map.getBounds().toArray().flat()
      let request =
      'https://my.server/search?q=' +
      config.query +
      '&format=geojson&addressdetails=1&viewbox='+geocoder_bbox;
      const response = await fetch(request);
      const geojson = await response.json();
      for (let feature of geojson.features) {
        let center = [
          feature.bbox[0] +
          (feature.bbox[2] - feature.bbox[0]) / 2,
          feature.bbox[1] +
          (feature.bbox[3] - feature.bbox[1]) / 2
        ];
        
          let point = {
            type: 'Feature',
            geometry: {
              type: 'Point',
              coordinates: center
            },
            place_name: feature.properties.display_name,
            properties: feature.properties,
            text: feature.properties.display_name,
            place_type: ['place'],
            center: center
          };
          features.push(point);
        }
      
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(`Failed to forwardGeocode with error: ${e}`);
    }

    return {
      features: features
    };
  }
};
```

Comment: https://github.com/osm-search/Nominatim/issues/1916 - this apparently is a known issue.

Comment: Other providers seem to handle that more conveniently. For example, Google Geocoder returns *Via Roma, Cagliari CA, Italy* and Bing returns *0) Via Roma, 09123 Cagliari Cagliari, Italy 1) Via Roma, 09124 Cagliari Cagliari, Italy*. MapBox has similar results.

Comment: unfortunately, using other providers is not an option for this project